# Having trouble with logic for a drink recipe database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am in the process of developing a database for an automated drink mixing robot, and I'm getting stuck with how to create the database.

In one table, I have a list of every possible ingredient (Coca-Cola, Pepsi, Smirnoff - Red Label, Skyy, etc.). A second table, lists which ingredients are available. A third table specifies the mixed drink recipes. My issue arises with the mixed drink table.

For example, if I wanted to order a Screw Driver, the robot would look to see if any vodka was available, and if any orange juice was available. However, if a drink recipe called for a specific type of vodka (such as Smirnoff - Red Label) I would want the robot to only use Smirnoff and not just any type of vodka.

So, does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could go about developing the database for such an application? I am thoroughly stumped with this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need some kind of hierarchy for your ingredients. So you would have "generics" like "cola", "vodka", "rum" etc and then the "brands" like "Coca-Cola", "Smirnoff", "Bacardi" etc

One way of achieving this is with two tables:

```
Generics
ID   -    Name
1    -    Cola
2    -    Vodka
etc

Ingredients
ID   - Generic_id  -  Name
1    -      1      -  Coca-Cola
2    -      1      -  Pepsi
3    -      2      -  Smirnoff - Red Label
4    -      2      -  Absolut
etc
```

Ps This sounds suspiciously like homework. If it is you should tag it as such...

Comment: Nope, its not actually homework. Its just an ambitious project that my roommate and I are building as a display for the electrical/computer engineering department at my university. Its actual intention is to attract incoming students to the electrical engineering field.

So, being the typical college student, we figured "what better way to attract engineering students then by showing off a robot that serves alcohol."

Our design is based off of Bar2D2 over at instructables, however, we've integrated an Android app that will allow you to order whatever drink you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more table "ingridient category" (ex. fruit juice, vodka, tequila) and reference ingredients table to this with FK. Then alter you receipt table, it should contain category or exact ingridient as a part of receipt.

Then, when robot looks for a ingridients it can decide, if he has exact ingridient or can choose from category list.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, its late and I didn't provide all of my database's information. I just realized I forgot to add that I do have a table that is category specific, just as you had suggested. The part that is throwing me, is the mixed_drink_ingredients table. Would I need an ingredient and category column for each potential ingredient that could appear in the drink?

Comment: Sounds good. You can add CHECK CONSTRAINT there, which will control that only one of two fields is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Split the ingredients into two tables: `ingredient_types` (i.e. vodka, juice, soft drink) and `ingredients` (i.e. Smirnoff, orange juice, cola). In the recipes reference either an ingredient type ("vodka") or specific ingredient ("Smirnoff").